# How to Plot density graph and line graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a big data-set in that three columns are there from those three columns I have to group-by the data by first columns and using the frequency of the first columns I need to plot the Line graph and Density graph. There are 1600 values counted in this graph.

some set of data are

```
Search keyword                         Campaign ID  total_ctr
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   15.38
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.00
        "2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore    653435194   0.0
  +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore    1155466985  0.00
+1 +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore   1155466985  0.00
+1 +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore   1155466985  0.00
+1 +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore   1155466985  100.00
+1 +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore   1155466985  0.00
+1 +bedroom +apartment +in +bangalore   1155466985  0.00
```

Like this the data set is goes for 22,200 lines and have 1600 search keyword have diffrent combination of total_ctr and campID.

some of thier frequency are

```
                                 Campaign ID     total_ctr
Search keyword      
"2 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore            24       24
+1 +bhk +flat +in +bangalore            89       89
+1 +bhk +flat +near +manyata tech park  23       23
+1 +bhk +flat +price +in +bangalore     15       15
+1 +bhk +flat +sale +bangalore           9       9
+1 +bhk +flats +bangalore               52       52
+1 +bhk +for +sale +in +bangalore       76       76
+1 +bhk +house +for +sale +in +bangalore20       20
+1 +bhk +in +bangalore +sale            61       61
+1 +bhk +in +north +bangalore           36       36
+1 +bhk +near +airport                  1         1
+1 +bhk +north +bangalore                8        8
+1bhk +apartment +in +bangalore         53       53
+1bhk +apartments +bangalore             9       9
+1bhk +bangalore                        118      118
+1bhk +flat +bangalore                   26       26
+1bhk +flats +bangalore                 107       107
+1bhk +near +airport                      4       4
+2 +3 +bhk +flats in +bangalore          50        50
```

From this frequency I want to plot 1600 plot in line and density graph in R or pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in df['Search keyword'].unique():
    xxx = df[df['Search keyword']==i]['total_ctr']
    jj =len(xxx)
    if jj>>29:
        print(jj)
        plt.plot(xxx)
        plt.title(i)
        plt.show()
        sns.kdeplot(xxx)
        plt.title(i + 'density')
        plt.show()
        plt.savefig('books_read.pdf')
```

This graph is only for density which you needed..